# Form Data is not being sent to server

Tags: php, html

The form created shows the data being sent within the URL when the submit is clicked however the only part which is sent to the server is the username/$un. All of form inputs are being ignored.

HTML Form:

```
<form action="CharacterAdd.php">
<legend>Add Character</legend>
Character Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="Name" >
<br>
Gender:<br>
<input type="text" name="Gender" >
<br>
Age:<br>
<input type="text" name="Age" >
<br>
Hobbies:<br>
<input type="text" name="Hobby" >
<br>
Home:<br>
<input type="text" name="Home" >
<br>
Job:<br>
<input type="text" name="Job" >
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<p>
<br>
</form>
```

PHP Code:

```
$un = $_SESSION["gatekeeper"];

$a = htmlentities($_POST['Name']);
$b = htmlentities($_POST['Gender']);
$c = htmlentities($_POST['Age']);
$d = htmlentities($_POST['Hobby']);
$e = htmlentities($_POST['Home']);
$f = htmlentities($_POST['Job']);
$g = htmlentities($_POST['$un']);

{
    $statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Characters(Name,Gender,Age,Hobby,Home,Job,username) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $statement->bindParam(1,$a);
    $statement->bindParam(2,$b);
    $statement->bindParam(3,$c);
    $statement->bindParam(4,$d);
    $statement->bindParam(5,$e);
    $statement->bindParam(6,$f);
    $statement->bindParam(7,$un);
    $statement->execute();
    $conn->query ($charac);
```

Comment: Where do you close the `<form>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to send the form with `POST`, change the method, as the default is `GET`

```
<form action="CharacterAdd.php" method="POST">
```

or you could check the `$_GET` superglobal instead

```
$a = htmlentities($_GET['Name']);
$b = htmlentities($_GET['Gender']);
```

Answer (score 1):

please declare method="POST" in form tag.

Answer (score 0):

You might be wrapping your PHP code like:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  ...
}
```

Which is a common mistake among developers, because in order for that to work, you need to name your submit button as **submit** like `<input name="submit" value="Submit form">`.
Also, you need to set some form attributes, such as the method and action. The default method is `get`. If you want your values hidden from the browser address bar, make sure you set your method to `post` like `<form method="post">. You also need to specify a file that will be called using`action`. If not set, the file within which the form is is taken as the action.